# QHash - hot to get a random key and value

Tags: c++, qt, iterator, random-access, qhash

I want to get a random pair with number `n` from my QHash.

Now I do it this way:

```
QHash<QString,QString>::iterator iterator = dictionary.begin();
iterator+= n;
question->setText(iterator.key());
```

But this seems just ridiculous... There must be a normal way. Can you help me please? I've read the whole entire man-page for QHash already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QHash` doesn't offer random selection. If you have to perform this operation often, then copy (pointers to) the `keys()` of the hash table into a `vector` or `QVector`, get a random index into that and use the key to look up the value in the `QHash`.

Depending on what else you use the `QHash` for, you might want to convert it to a vector of pairs at some point and just use that for random selection.

Comment: I need to store a 2-language dictionary in it. Seems like it's nice to store it sorted, right? I will need to do 2 operations. 1 - Get a random pair. 2 - Check if there is value-key pair in it. What do you advise to use? Maybe a `QMap`?

Comment: @Kolyunya: do you regularly insert items into the `QHash`, or is it fixed at some point?

Comment: It's definitely fixed. It's formed only once.

Comment: @Kolyunya: then you can store the key-value pairs in a `vector` when input is done, sort the vector and use binary search to look up keys.

Comment: Thanks in advance! OFFTOPIC: I'm very new to Qt and it seems me a nice lib, thus I wonder why `C` questions here have 20 times more views and answers than `Qt`. It is so unpopular here?

Comment: @Kolyunya: I wouldn't be surprised if C is much more popular than Qt all-round, because it's much more broadly applicable and widely taught in colleges.